# What is the etymology of parseltongue/parselmouth?

Tags: harry-potter, terminology

Where/how did Rowling come up with the terms "parseltongue" and "parselmouth"? Are they inspired by, or in any way rooted in, relevant real-world words/terms (perhaps related to snakes), or was it something she just came up with "out of the blue"?

Comment: J. K. Rowling has stated that she took the name Parselmouth from an "old word for someone who has a problem with the mouth, like a hare lip"

Answer (score 8):

From JKR's [interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2003/0626-alberthall-fry.htm) with Stephen Fry at Albert Hall in 2003:

> **SF**: [...] is a Parselmouth a real thing or did you make that up?
>
> **JKR**: Parselmouth is an old word for someone who has a problem with the mouth, like a hare lip.

There are plenty of Q&A sites discussing the etymology of this word, but none have found an adequate real-life example. It seems that JKR either dug very deep or made it up.

Comment: Well, "Parsemouth" does appear as a surname, once, as Google has found: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=german+last+names+%22Parsemouth%22

Answer (score 1):

In the French translation of *Harry Potter*, Parseltongue is translated "fourchelangue" (Fourche = Fork, Langue = Tongue/Language).

"Forked Tongue" may refer to the snake's bifurcated tongue. And the dual meaning Tongue/Language of "langue" is interesting in this case. It's true that "parsel" sounds like "partiel" meaning incomplete, that may refer once again to the snake's tongue.

JK Rowling speaks very good French, so she might had to use that language to find original words in her books. She is actually a French descendant. Voldemort is  good example, is made up from French "vol de mort", literally meaning "theft of death". "De" is also equivalent to Lord.

Comment: Re: Voldemort, I'm certainly not contradicting you but "vol" can also mean "fly", giving the intriguing possibility that Voldemort means "Fly/flies from death" - one who is trying to escape death itself. That's almost certainly not the case (my French is _extremely_ rusty, to say the least) but given that just about everything Voldemort has done seems to be to prevent his own death it has always struck me as possible, however unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the word "parselmouth" nor "parsel" appear to have an Old English root.  "Parsel" doesn't appear to exist until Middle English, as a term for parsley.

However, "parsel" does appear in Old French, and Rowling has a degree in French literature.

Comment: And what does "parsel" mean in Old French?

Comment: @lfurini - I assume they're talking about Parsley? - https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED33078